# Can I maintain a reference to the GL10 safely?

Tags: android, opengl-es

In my android application I get a reference to the GL10 object in the methods: onSurfaceCreated, onSurfaceChanged, and onDrawFrame.  Is it safe to hold onto that reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't store a reference from your `GL10` pointer.

It's only valid for the three overrided methods, `onSurfaceChanged()`, `onSurfaceCreated()` and `onDrawFrame()`. OpenGL ES uses state change and therefore is the OpenGL ES context only valid inside these methods.

It may look safe, mainly because `onDrawFrame()` will be iterated over and over by the GL thread, which will make your OpenGL ES context "activated" during these calls.